# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

For near by connection Im getting this issue on failed connecion

Can any one faced this issue, I'm using all latest google dependeeencies

com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

Comment: Same issue. Using the simple app from github. On older phone (Android 6) no issues. Newer phone (Android 9) - the similar message as above. AI suggests the Nearby feature or radios are off or permissions aren't granted. But that's not the case (all enabled and granted).

Comment: Same issue.  Getting this both with my app and the sample walkie talkie app from Google.  I'm on Android 14.

Answer (score 1):

Your device must have google play service. You can use the following code to check the device if it has google play service.

```
private fun isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(): Boolean {
    val availability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = availability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        availability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 0)?.show()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```